# How to simulate session closing / expiring in Spring Boot tests?

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot, spring-test, mockmvc

I would like to add a couple of tests to the example shown here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

to be able to verify that a user can no longer access resources requiring authentication when session closes or expires. I would like to simulate both the following conditions in my tests:

a) the user voluntarily ends their session (e.g. close their browser);

b) the session times out;

I don't know how to reproduce those conditions using MockMvc.

I managed to do the following:

```
@Test
public void sessionIsInvalid() throws Exception {
    FormLoginRequestBuilder login = formLogin()
            .user("user")
            .password("password");

    mockMvc.perform(login)
            .andExpect(authenticated())
            .andDo(mvcResult -> {
                MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession)mvcResult.getRequest().getSession();
                session.invalidate();
                mockMvc.perform(get("/hello")
                        .session(session))
                        .andExpect(status().isFound());
            });
}
```

...which seems to work but I am not totally sure what `invalidate` does in this context and whether it matches condition a) above.

To emulate the session timeout, I've done instead:

```
@Test
public void sessionExpires() throws Exception {
    FormLoginRequestBuilder login = formLogin()
            .user("user")
            .password("password");

    mockMvc.perform(login)
            .andExpect(authenticated())
            .andDo(mvcResult -> {
                MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession)mvcResult.getRequest().getSession();
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1);
                Thread.sleep(3);
                mockMvc.perform(get("/hello")
                        .session(session))
                        .andExpect(status().isFound());
            });
}
```

...but this **doesn't** work. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot with Spring Security (which is all about in you link), my approach is this:

- create a custom spring security filter that is able to "convince" spring security that the *session* is expired (whatever it believes a *session* is)
- add the custom filter just before `ConcurrentSessionFilter`
- create an inner static `@TestConfiguration` class which could, in theory, just configure the `HttpSecurity` to add the custom filter (that's all we want). In practice I found that usually I have to have the class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` to extend my project's security configuration class (or at least the main one, if having many, e.g. `SecurityConfiguration` for my project); because in `SecurityConfiguration` I usually declare other `@Bean` too (e.g. `CorsConfigurationSource`) I usually have to also use `@WebMvcTest(properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true", ...)` to avoid the bean overriding error; have the class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` to be annotated with `@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` too.
- create a simple web mvc test trying to `GET` some project-existing endpoint, e.g.:

```java
@Test
@SneakyThrows
@WithMockUser
void sessionExpired() {
    this.mvc.perform(get("/some-endpoint-here")).andExpect(...);
}
```

- run the test and expect for your configured *session expiration strategy* to kick in; see `HttpSecurity.sessionManagement(session -> session...expiredUrl(...))` or `HttpSecurity.sessionManagement(session -> session...expiredSessionStrategy(...))`

The below spring security configuration provided as a `@TestConfiguration` works with Spring Boot 2.3.12.RELEASE (and probably many more).

```java
@TestConfiguration
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
static class Config extends SecurityConfiguration {
    public Config(SessionInformationExpiredStrategy expiredSessionStrategy, InvalidSessionStrategy invalidSessionStrategy) {
        super(expiredSessionStrategy, invalidSessionStrategy);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        super.configure(http);
        // the custom filter as a lambda expression
        http.addFilterBefore((request, response, chain) -> {
            // preparing some objects we gonna need
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            // getting our hands on the object that Spring Security believes
            // is the "session" and which is in ConcurrentSessionFilter
            List<Filter> filters = (List) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(chain, "additionalFilters");
            int currentPosition = (int) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(chain, "currentPosition");
            ConcurrentSessionFilter concurrentSessionFilter = (ConcurrentSessionFilter) filters.get(currentPosition);
            SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = (SessionRegistry) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(concurrentSessionFilter, "sessionRegistry");
            // the "session" does not exist (from Spring Security's PoV), 
            // we actually have to create (aka "register") it
            sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(session.getId(), authentication.getPrincipal());
            // the actual session expiration (from Spring Security's PoV)
            sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(session.getId()).expireNow();
            // let the filters continue their job; ConcurrentSessionFilter
            // follows and it'll determine that the "session" is expired
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }, ConcurrentSessionFilter.class);
        log.debug("begin");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1);  // in seconds

Thread.sleep(3);  // in milliseconds
```

Comment: please add explanation to your answer